# Detect Speech Activity (2 Speakers) in an audio recording

Tags: python, audio, nlp, voice-recording, text-segmentation

**Goal:**
I want to extract the segments (timecodes) of speech activity in an audio recording containing two speakers. Optimally the solution should assign a label to the segments "Speaker 1" or "Speaker 2".

**Problem:**
I found VAD (Voice Activity Detection) and Speaker Identification. However I am not quite sure that this is what I am looking for, because VAD doesn't deliver the labels (Speaker 1 or 2) and Speaker Identification seems to be too high level (since it is used for authentification over multiple session) and I only got a few recordings (~10 with different speakers on every recording.)

**Question:**
Is there a solution for my problem (automatic segmentation)? Am I searching for the right phrases (*VAD* and *Speaker Identification*). Can you recommend an easy to implement VAD Python library?

Comment: You are searching for a speaker diarization algorithm, VAD and Speaker Identification are part of the pipeline you are going to have to extract the timecodes... I am researching this, how did your project go?

Comment: Ty for the reply. Not to well, my funding got cut so I had to start my phd over at another university and with it my topic. Best wishes for your research